# How to grow/shrink a DialogFragment when dynamically showing/hiding an EditText?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have a very simple Dialog:

[image]

On click of the button I would like to toggle visibility of the second EditText:

```
public class SomeDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_dialog, container, false);

        EditText editSecond = root.findViewById(R.id.text_second);
        Button buttonOk = root.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);

        buttonOk.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            editSecond.setVisibility(editSecond.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

I would like it to be animated smoothly, so I set "animateLayoutChanges" to "true":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large.Inverse"
        android:textSize="18sp"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First"
    />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Second"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Ok"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The dialog gets animated, but unfortunately not in the correct order.

What happens:

1. the TextEdit vanishes
2. the Dialog height snaps (instantly) to the smaller height
3. the Button moves up (animated)

So between 2) and 3) the button is not visible and slowly slides into the (already smaller) dialog from offscreen (bottom).

What can be done about this?

(Code Sample works and can be copy/pasted into Android Studio as is)